# Need to make deviceorientation recognized on iphone safari through localhost

Tags: ios, safari, localhost, device-orientation

I'm building a mobile web that needs to read device orientation value from iphone, and the other webpage that gets the value.

This project is going to be displayed in the exhibition, so I'm planning to use USB to connect mobile and the macbook through localhost for realtime response.

But when I see it on iphone by connecting it to my localhost, device orientation value cannot be read.

https://medium.com/@wiekatz/testing-web-applications-running-on-localhost-with-an-iphone-7db6258b8f2

I followed this instruction to connect the device to localhost, and the connection works fine so that I can see it on my phone. I checked that other features like recognizing which button has been clicked are working fine in realtime.

I could see device orientation working when I deploy this to other domain and check on the phone, but I need to make this working through localhost.

Let me know if there's any clue what is causing this!

```
//mobile.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

    <title>Mobile PtoR</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile_style.css" />
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="closewrapper"><button id="closebutton">x</button></div>
      <div class="iconwrapper">

          <div class="icons" id="AppBank"><p>Bank</p></div>
          <div class="icons" id="AppWeather"><p>Weather</p></div>
          <div class="icons" id="AppDict"><p>Dictionary</p></div>
          <div class="icons" id="AppFb"><p>Facebook</p></div>
          <div class="icons" id="AppCal"><p>Calendar</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="sensorcheck">
    <h1>Device Orientation API</h1>
    <span id="do-unsupported" class="hidden"
      >deviceorientation event not supported</span
    >
    <span id="dm-unsupported" class="hidden"
      >devicemotion event not supported</span
    >
    <span id="cnc-unsupported" class="hidden"
      >compassneedscalibration event not supported</span
    >

    <div id="do-results">
       <div id="cube" class="cube">
        <div class="face one">1</div>
        <div class="face two">2</div>
        <div class="face three">3</div>
        <div class="face four">4</div>
        <div class="face five">5</div>
        <div class="face six">6</div>
      </div> 
      <div id="do-info" class="hidden">
        <p>
          Coordinates: (<span id="beta" class="value">null</span>,
          <span id="gamma" class="value">null</span>,
          <span id="alpha" class="value">null</span>)
          <br />
          Position absolute?
          <span id="is-absolute" class="value">unavailable</span>
        </p>
      </div>
       <div id="dm-info" class="hidden">
        <p>
          Acceleration: (<span id="acceleration-x" class="value">null</span>,
          <span id="acceleration-y" class="value">null</span>,
          <span id="acceleration-z" class="value">null</span>) m/s<sup>2</sup>
        </p>
        <p>
          Acceleration including gravity: (<span
            id="acceleration-including-gravity-x"
            class="value"
            >null</span
          >,
          <span id="acceleration-including-gravity-y" class="value">null</span>,
          <span id="acceleration-including-gravity-z" class="value">null</span>)
          m/s<sup>2</sup>
        </p>
        <p>
          Rotation rate: (<span id="rotation-rate-beta" class="value">null</span
          >, <span id="rotation-rate-gamma" class="value">null</span>,
          <span id="rotation-rate-alpha" class="value">null</span>)
        </p>
        <p>Interval: <span id="interval" class="value">0</span> milliseconds</p>
      </div> 
    </div>


</div>
    <script>
      if (!window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
        document.getElementById("do-unsupported").classList.remove("hidden")
      } else {
        document.getElementById("do-info").classList.remove("hidden")

        window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function(event) {
          document.getElementById(
            "cube"
          ).style.webkitTransform = document.getElementById(
            "cube"
          ).style.transform =
            "rotateX(" +
            event.beta +
            "deg) " +
            "rotateY(" +
            event.gamma +
            "deg) " +
            "rotateZ(" +
            event.alpha +
            "deg)"

          document.getElementById("beta").innerHTML = Math.round(event.beta)
          document.getElementById("gamma").innerHTML = Math.round(event.gamma)
          document.getElementById("alpha").innerHTML = Math.round(event.alpha)
          document.getElementById("is-absolute").innerHTML = event.absolute
            ? "true"
            : "false"
        })
      }

    </script>
    <!--      Custom fuctions of firebase-->
    <script src="mobileFirebase.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
//mobileFirebase.js 
//the value is passed to firebase

var firebaseConfig = {
--------
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
var firestore = firebase.firestore()


/* define things to be used*/
const AppBank = document.querySelector("#AppBank")
const AppWeather = document.querySelector("#AppWeather")
const AppDict = document.querySelector("#AppDict")
const AppFb = document.querySelector("#AppFb")
const AppCal = document.querySelector("#AppCal")
const closewrapper = document.querySelector("#closewrapper")
const closebutton = document.querySelector("#closebutton")

//const CurrentStatus = "landing"
const DOsensorRef = firestore.doc("status/DOsensor")
const docRef = firestore.doc("status/ClickStatus")


/* device orientation */
if (!window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
  document.getElementById("do-unsupported").classList.remove("hidden")
} else {
  document.getElementById("do-info").classList.remove("hidden")

  window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function(event) {
    const val_beta = Math.round(event.beta)
    const val_gamma = Math.round(event.gamma)
    const val_alpha = Math.round(event.alpha)

    console.log(
      "beta : ",
      val_beta,
      "gamma : ",
      val_gamma,
      "alpha : ",
      val_alpha
    )

    DOsensorRef.set({
      fire_beta: val_beta,
      fire_alpha: val_alpha,
      fire_gamma: val_gamma
    })
      .then(function() {
        console.log("in sync")
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
  })
}



/* status recognize */
closebutton.addEventListener("click", function(){

    closewrapper.style.display="none"
    const CurrentStatus = "Landing"
    docRef.set({
      AppStatus: CurrentStatus
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log("Status changed!")
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("got an error: ", error)
    })
})

AppBank.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const CurrentStatus = "Bank"

  docRef.set({
      AppStatus: CurrentStatus
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log("Status changed!")
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("got an error: ", error)
    })

  closewrapper.style.display="block"
})


AppWeather.addEventListener("click", function() {
const CurrentStatus = "Weather"

  docRef.set({
      AppStatus: CurrentStatus
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log("Status changed!")
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("got an error: ", error)
    })
    closewrapper.style.display="block"

})

AppDict.addEventListener("click", function() {
const CurrentStatus = "Dictionary"

  docRef.set({
      AppStatus: CurrentStatus
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log("Status changed!")
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("got an error: ", error)
    })
    closewrapper.style.display="block"

})


AppFb.addEventListener("click", function() {
const CurrentStatus = "Facebook"

  docRef.set({
      AppStatus: CurrentStatus
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log("Status changed!")
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("got an error: ", error)
    })
    closewrapper.style.display="block"

})


AppCal.addEventListener("click", function() {
const CurrentStatus = "Calendar"

  docRef.set({
      AppStatus: CurrentStatus
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log("Status changed!")
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("got an error: ", error)
    })
    closewrapper.style.display="block"

})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem yesterday. Your localhost probably does not run on https  but on http. So certain features as device orientation gets blocked. You are only able to use them in a [secure context](https://www.w3.org/TR/secure-contexts/).

Easy solution is to tunnel your local server to the outside e.g. with https://localtunnel.github.io/www/

or make your own secure certificate for your local webserver. Maybe you can find some infos [here](https://deliciousbrains.com/https-locally-without-browser-privacy-errors/).

Comment: Hi Stefan! Thanks to your answer, I managed to set a certificate with a similar method from the last link you posted. So both my laptop and the device is running on https from the same certificate. But now it cannot get the deviceorientation sensor value from the device in realtime which I intended to. There's a huge delay. Do you have any clue how can I manage this to be in realtime?

Comment: Hi Seungmee, i'm sadly not that deeply involved in that subject. But my first guess is that probably you use an old encryption method in your certificate.  Maybe https://istlsfastyet.com can help you find some tipps to optimize your connection